# what is the difference between creating type of the class and creating instance of the class

Tags: swift

I noticed that

**Program A**

```
 var okie=Int(2)

 print(okie)
```

**Program B**

```
 var okie:Int=2

 print(okie)
```

**Output**

2

I noticed that program A and program b works on the same way, Can any on elaborate what is happening

Comment: What do you mean by _Creating type of the class_, I guess, in both the cases you are creating an _instance of type **Int**_ . It's just that in _Program B_, you're _inferring the type to be Int_ .

Comment: If you go with this https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html, then you get your solution